# FMOD don't play sound C++

Tags: c++, fmod

I actually try to play a sound with FMOD but it didn't work.

```
#ifndef __SOUND_HH__
#define __SOUND_HH__

#include <string>
#include <fmodex/fmod.h>

class Sound
{
  FMOD_SYSTEM *sys;

  FMOD_SOUND *explosion;
  FMOD_RESULT resExplosion;
  FMOD_CHANNEL *channel1;

public:
  Sound();
  ~Sound();

  void play(const std::string &);
};

#endif
```

and

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Sound.hh"

Sound::Sound()
{
  FMOD_System_Create(&this->sys);
  FMOD_System_Init(this->sys, 1, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, NULL);
}

Sound::~Sound()
{
  FMOD_System_Release(sys);
}
```

but when I do play("mysound.wav"); on my code nothing append, I verify return value and no problem. so any idea ? thanks

```
void Sound::play(const std::string &filename)
{
  FMOD_System_CreateStream(this->sys, filename.c_str(), FMOD_HARDWARE | FMOD_LOOP_OFF | FMOD_2D, 0, &this->explosion);
  FMOD_System_PlaySound(sys, FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, explosion, 0 , &channel1);
        std::cout << "playayayyayayayayya" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you turned on/up your speakers? Have you tried playing the sound through a media player?

Comment: I have try with an other project in C where I use FMOD and it's work. I try with a same sound and always don't work

Comment: where's the code where you are calling the play function?

Comment: I code a bomberman game so, I call the play function on a class Bomb when the bomb explodes. and I have a Sound *_sound variable on my class. I do _sound = new Sound() on the constructor, and call _sound->play(file) when I need it

Comment: yeah we need to see that code, exactly as you have it in your game

Comment: `void            Bombe::update(const gdl::GameClock & gameClock, gdl::Input & input)
{
  (void)input;
  this->_time += gameClock.getElapsedTime();
  if (this->_time > EXPLODE)
    {
      this->_boum = true;
      this->_sound.play("./sound/explosion.wav");
    }
    if (this->_time > FLAMME)
    this->_pshh = true;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You're not dynamically allocating the `Sound` variable.

What you need is:

`Sound sound = new Sound();`

`sound->play("./sound/explosion.wav");`

Or in  the `Bombe::update` do:

`Sound sound;`

`sound.play("./sound/explosion.wav");`

Also make sure that `explosion.wav` is in the folder `sound/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it's work, but FMOD don't have sound, all my other sound work. that a problem ...

Comment: have you checked the file is in the folder you are passing in? Also what OS are you doing this in?

Comment: yes yes, and I'm on ubuntu x64. it's weird cause I use FMOD in the past and it work good.

Comment: it's very strange, try passing in another file that you know works.